# Using conditional if statement for plotshape

Tags: pine-script

I have problem with following code, and would appreciate help:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Example", shorttitle="Ex", overlay=true)

//Average volume, 45 periods
sum = volume[1]
for i = 1 to 45
    sum := sum + volume[i]
volumeMA = sum / 45
VolumeRatio = volume/volumeMA

//Calculate Scores - Volume
VolumeScore = 0
if VolumeRatio > 1 and VolumeRatio < 1.5 
    VolumeScore := 1
if VolumeRatio >= 1.5 and VolumeRatio < 2 
    VolumeScore := 2
if VolumeRatio >= 2 
    VolumeScore := 3

//Calculate Scores - HH
HH_Bull = 0
if high >= highest(high, 5)
    HH_Bull := 1    
if high >= highest(high, 8)
    HH_Bull := 2    
if high >= highest(high, 14)
    HH_Bull := 3

HH_Bear = 0
if low >= lowest(low, 3)
    HH_Bear := 1    
if low >= lowest(low, 6)
    HH_Bear := 2    
if low >= lowest(low, 10)
    HH_Bear := 3

//Caclulate Total Score
Candle_Bull_Score = VolumeScore + HH_Bull
Candle_Bear_Score = VolumeScore + HH_Bear

BullCandle = close > close[1] and open-low >= 10
BearCandle = close < close[1] and high-open >= 10

plotshape(BullCandle, title= "Bull", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY-" & Candle_Bull_Score)
plotshape(BearCandle, title= "Bear", location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="SELL-" & Candle_Bear_Score)
```

Please note that I have deliberately combined `text="Buy" & Candle_Bull_Score`, aware that it won't work just to explain what I'm trying to do.
I want to plot the "BullCandle" variable but give the indication of the signal strength by using Candle_Bull_Score and Candle_Bear_Score.

Answer (score 1):

See comments in code:

```
//@version=4
study("Volume Ratio", "", true)
//Calculate Scores - Volume
VolumeRatio = roc(volume, 1)
VolumeScore = 0

// Note the ":=" assignment operator so you don't redeclare local vars in "if" blocks.
// Also note "case" structure so you are testing exclusively. Not essential but more elegant and negligibly faster.
if VolumeRatio > 1 and VolumeRatio < 1.5 
    VolumeScore:=1
else
    if VolumeRatio >= 1.5 and VolumeRatio < 2 
        VolumeScore:=2
    else
        if VolumeRatio >= 2 
            VolumeScore:=3

// Note "==" operator for logical test. The 3 "pltoshape()" calls are necessary, as there's no way to use 
//  a "series string" (i.e., varying dynamically during script's execution) argument for "text=".
plotshape(VolumeScore==1, title= "Case1", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY-1")
plotshape(VolumeScore==2, title= "Case2", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY-2")
plotshape(VolumeScore==3, title= "Case3", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY-3")

// With labels we can use a series string, but only the last ~50 will appear on chart.
if VolumeScore > 0
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(VolumeScore, "BUY- #"), xloc.bar_index, yloc.abovebar, color.lime, label.style_triangleup, color.lime, size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I should have been more clear as I wrongly changed variable names in the example script to make it easier to read, but I was trying to plot CandleA (Case1 in previous example) and CandleB (Case2 in previous example), while assigning text based on Volume Strength.

Also, the score is assigned based on Volume and two more calculations, whereas each calculation has 3 potential points, summing to 9 points and 0 if none of the conditions are met. In total there is 10 values for strength of the signal, which makes a lot of potential combinations.

Comment: I have edited the code to make my attempt more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Due to previous answer, I have managed to solve my issue. Thank You LucF!

I have combined IF statement with "label.new" and "tostring", without plot command, to get what I wanted. Seems to work perfectly.

This solved it:

```
if close > close[1] and open-low >= 10    
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(Candle_Bull_Score, "BUY- #"), xloc.bar_index, yloc.belowbar, color.lime, label.style_triangleup, color.lime, size.small)
```